# How to use toggle css classes on an element onclick?

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript

Using angular typescript, not $scope.  I seen a ton of examples for $scope or JQuery.  I want to basically have a clickable ellipsis, that will remove the overflow and text-overflow properties of the class when clicked, so I can expand the full text of the div I am truncating.  I believe it looks like I want to use ng-class, or make a function for an ng-click, but I can't find any examples that don't use $scope.class, and I it isn't like I can just use a this.class in typescript.

Here are the css classes I am trying to toggle:

```
.homeDescriptionDiv {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.homeDescriptionDiv2 {
}
```

here is the html element, sans any Angular references:

```
<div class="col-md-12 homeDescriptionDiv" ng-click="changeClass()">
                                <h4>
                                    Description
                                </h4>
                                {{challenge.description}}
                            </div>
```

The typescript in my controller would look something like:

```
element.class = class1;
function changeClass(){
this.class=class2
}
```

Ulltimately, I would love to be able to toggle back and forth by clicking again, but removing the first class is the core requirement.  Thanks!

Comment: please post a code example. it will help us find your problem.

Comment: also, I would advise you to read the how to ask a good question guide. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks, sorry, I try, but I'm new and tired and way over-caffeinated today!  I have posted the code I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you controller have a property `showClass` and then bind it to the element like `ng-class="{'some-class': vm.showClass}"`

Now if `showClass` is true then element gets `some-class` otherwise `some-class` is removed. The toggle function on the controller is just `this.showClass = !this.showClass`